# How to get PostgreSQL/psycopg2 to work, Windows XP, ValueError: [u'path']

Tags: python, postgresql, windows-xp, psycopg2

I've been using SQLite as my database for the past few months while learning django and building a website.  I finally decided it was time to make the switch to PostgreSQL as I am getting closer to production.  I have been stuck for several days chasing down error after error, viewing basically every other post and trying to get it to work, but I still haven't been able to have any luck.  Most recently, I tried following http://web.archive.org/web/20101221084639/http://nukeit.org/compile-python-2-7-packages-with-visual-studio-2010-express/ but I am still getting errors.  The most recent traceback when running pip install psycopg2 is as follows:

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
    Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

        no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\src\_build'
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\projects\xLFTV\lftv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 557, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\projects\xLFTV\lftv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 275, in build_extension
        build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 474, in compile
        self.initialize()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 384, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 300, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Documents and Settings\\user
\\projects\\xLFTV\\lftv\\build\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\docume~1\user\locals~1\temp\pip-v_thso-record\install-
record.txt:
running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\projects\xLFTV\lftv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 557, in <module>

        ext_modules=ext)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run

        return _install.run(self)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

        self.run_command('build')

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

        self.run_command(cmd_name)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run

        self.build_extensions()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions

        self.build_extension(ext)

    File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\projects\xLFTV\lftv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 275, in build_extension

        build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension

        depends=ext.depends)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 474, in compile

        self.initialize()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 384, in initialize

        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 300, in query_vcvarsall

        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

  ValueError: [u'path']
```

Sorry if it's a little messy.  I tried to clean it up as much as I could before posting it.  I am fairly new to programming, and I am at a complete loss as to what else I should try.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I have already seen 3 other error messages along the way in my progression, and have had to do several other downloads trying to get this to work.  I am open to any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get an error on the last line of installing Pylons 1.0 with easy_install and Python 2.7 in Windows Vista 64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827170/why-do-i-get-an-error-on-the-last-line-of-installing-pylons-1-0-with-easy-instal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar story as you...  I banged my head against a wall for days trying to get things to work.  The easiest way to solve your problem is to find/download/install the prebuilt package.  You can find a list of them (including psycopg2) [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  -- BIG thanks to Christoph Gohlke to maintaining these.

As a reference, you can see my posting on a related topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012086/heroku-tutorial-with-pip-virtualenv-psycopg2-django-on-windows-7).

Finally, let me offer a piece of free advice.  If you really want to work in Python/Django, it's just easier to switch to Linux.  Probably 90+% of all of the blog posts or "how to's" assume you are running some flavor of Linux.  I started by downloading VirtualBox from Oracle and installing Ubuntu in it.  That was good enough for a long time.  But, I eventually switch to a dual boot set up and I RARELY ever going into windows any more.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the help and advice.  Got it all finally working now, after a huge headache. So I have only ever worked with Windows... is it fairly easy to make the switch to Linux?

Comment: Ubuntu makes it extremely easy.  I started off with a VM installed in VirtualBox, but eventually switched to a dual boot (the VM was a bit slow) and I'm happy that I did.  Again, if you are going to work with Python (or virtually any open source technology) then Linux is probably going to make your life a lot easier.  There are tons of how-tos out there to install Ubuntu along side Windows, and there is an official windows install at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, but I don't think it will allow you to configure your partition size.  I went with the full install from a USB drive.